# In Objective-C, how do I reanimate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

UIImageView *circleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face.png"]];
circleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);

circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 100;
circleView.center = self.view.center;

[self.view addSubview:circleView];
circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.5 initialSpringVelocity:1 options:0 animations:^{
    circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
} completion:nil];
```

As you can see, I made a view called circleView in this animation method. Then, I created a touchesBegan method and I want to run through the animation again when touching the screen. How should I do that?

Comment: The question is not clear, brief ur question ?

Comment: Add animation code in **touchesBegan method**

Comment: So, I want create a touchesBegan method, and when the screen is touched it animates again instead of adding a new subview and animate.

Comment: I got it now by creating a property and I can use it wherever I want. The problem now is with the animation. When I touch the screen, I don't want it t to appear out of nowhere. I just want the picture to bounce.

Answer (score 0):

As Sujay said, create a new method and put below lines inside that method. Call that method from touchBegan method.

```
circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.5 initialSpringVelocity:1 options:0 animations:^{
    circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: how do I use the circleView in this method? It says undeclared identifier

Comment: I got it now by creating a property and I can use it wherever I want. The problem now is with the animation. When I touch the screen, I don't want it t to appear out of nowhere. I just want the picture to bounce

Answer (score 0):

I did it. I created 2 properties and I made an animation where it gets small, then another animation that makes to make it bigger.